# npm open is not working while deploying it in server?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a nodejs code where at some point it uses a new tab for showing results.I got npm-open where it show my result in a new tab of the browser.But when i deploy it in a linux server, its neither opening a new tab nor throwing any error?

```
open( req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host')+"/view-document/?logos="+ logos+"&comp_name="+result_3[0].name +"&emp_name="+empname+"&start_date="+sdates+"&end_date="+edates+"&position="+designation+"&template=template1"+"&emp_id="+emp_id+"&issue_date="+issue_date+"&title="+title, function (err) {
                if ( err ) {
                    res.redirect("/view-document/?logos=" + logos+"&comp_name="+result_3[0].name +"&emp_name="+empname+"&start_date="+sdates+"&end_date="+edates+"&position="+designation+"&template=template1"+"&emp_id="+emp_id+"&issue_date="+issue_date+"&title="+title);
                    return;
                }    
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

How could it?

The `open` command is a way to make your script interact with the OS it is running on, telling it to open a URL, image, etc. If you run your script on your local machine, this is fine and works as expected.

If you run your script on a server, there is no way it can communicate its request to your local machine. Think about it – should a random webpage/server have the ability to interact with the OS on client machines?

To make something like this work, you will need to split your script into two parts:

- the parts that should reside on the server
- the utility script which will communicate with the server and, when needed, run the `open` command

Comment: Is there any way, so that server open a new tab on client browser?

Comment: As I said, you will need to split your script into two parts, one for the server, one running on the client machine. There is no way to have `open`-like functionality without some script or native application running on the client's machine due to security reasons.